# I download the english tor for 32bit windows. I install tor. I cannot use tor as it has no language, just llllllllll lll llllll lll. huh?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, help

I can not change the language as I have no way of reading anything. the setup looks like my old firefox setup, but icons do not match up so I can't guess which icon matches to language!!
the language of my windows 7 is english for everything (keyboard, locale, etc)
but the language of tor is IIIII IIII II  IIIII. III.

I have taken screenshots. I re-downloaded from https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en#downloads (windows ver4.5.1) with the same results. I will try installing to another directory.

tor browser language

here is an example of the language issue I am having with tor browser. updated browser by guessing which buttons were what. now at version 4.5.2
[image: tor browser language]

I tried installing to a different directory. same problem with language.
[image: diff dir install]

running windows 7, 32 bit, OKAYfreedom (turned off)

Comment: Can you provide us with a screenshot? What exact version did you download from what site?

Comment: I've never heard of this. Have you compared the signatures of the file you downloaded to the one on the site? Or simply just re-downloaded it.

Comment: I have taken screenshots, but do not understand how to insert them in my reply.
I re-downloaded from https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en#downloads (windows ver3.4.1)
with the same results.
I will try installing to another directory.

Comment: Could you give me your exact device details? It might just not be rendering properly on your screen resolution/proccessor speed.